# ggplot2 geom_density plot splits around 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a piece of R code that analyses differences over time in two sensor readings. As such, they center around a mean of 0.

```
b = 30 # Number of bins
xl = -.025  # Hard axis limit on left x value 
xr = .025  # Hard axis limit on right x value 
yl = 0 # Hard axis limit on left y value (always 0)
yr = 120  # Hard axis limit on right y value

diff1 %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=value, geom="line"), position="identity") +
   geom_histogram(bins=b, fill="#0000FF") + 
   geom_density(alpha=.1, fill="#000000") +
   xlim(xl, xr) +  
   ylim(yl, yr)
```

I would like to show a continuous distribution overlay using the geom_density function,
but I get something like below.

[image: ggplot image output]

As you see, there is a split on the value around 0, but I can't figure out how I can get rid of it. I tried different AES options, none of them providing fruitful results. I would like to show a single continues geom_density line, instead of two groups. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `diff1`??

Comment: What happens if you remove the `ylim`?

Comment: @Bas, thanks for the suggestion. This was the issue, I was digging to deep here :)

Comment: @Duck, it's a dataframe that contains values@t1 - values@t2. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bas pointed out, the visualisation got cut off by my axis limits. The following code did the trick. Hopefully, my answer can help someone in the future!

```
diff1 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=value, geom="line"), position="identity") +
    geom_histogram(bins=b, fill="#0000FF") + 
    geom_density(alpha=.1, fill="#000000") +
    xlim(xl, xr)
```

[image]